# Django template conditionals not working as intended

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to create a basic view which returns a bunch of posts to be rendered as per the given keyword. I want it to be such that:

1. When it loads initially, it just shows a search bar.
2. When a keyword is supplied for search then it finds the posts with that keyword and renders them.
3. If no posts are found then it should show a message that "no posts for the given keyword were found".

I am able to achieve 1 and 2 but for the 3rd one, django is acting strange.

Views.py

```py
def search(request):
    if 'keyword' in request.GET and request.GET['keyword'] != '' and request.GET['keyword'] != ' ':
        res = Post.objects.filter(tag__icontains=request.GET['keyword'])
        posts = [PostSerializer(x).data for x in res]
        if len(posts) == 0:
            return render(request, 'search.html', context={'notfound':True})
        return render(request, 'search.html', context={'posts':posts})
    return render(request, 'search.html')
```

Template

```
{% if notfound %}
    <h2> Seems like there are no posts with that keyword </h2>
{% endif %}
        
{% for post in posts %}
    //render posts
{% endfor %}
```

Note that here I have used the 'notfound' key as simply checking if posts | length equals 0 was achieving 3 (the 3 points mentioned above) but was also showing the message for 1, which is not wanted.

Anyway, the desirable output here is that if there is no context then it should just show the search bar. If `notfound` exists then it should display that "Not Found" message and if it doesn't exist then the message isn't displayed and the posts go on to be rendered.

However it is not working. The message just doesn't appear. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you're using the PostSerializer, but here is a method that should work.

```
def search(request):
    if 'keyword' in request.GET and request.GET['keyword'].strip() != '':
        res = Post.objects.filter(tag__icontains=request.GET['keyword'])
        if res.count() == 0:
            return render(request, 'search.html', context={'notfound':True})
        return render(request, 'search.html', context={'posts':posts})
    return render(request, 'search.html')
```

Comment: No, it's having the same effect as {% if posts|length == 0 %} which causes the message to show even when the page just loads up without any context passed. You don't want to show "not found" message before the user has even searched anything 

Comment: Ok but why are you serializing your Posts and not directly pass them in the context ?

Comment: For formatting the fields and adding a few things as per requirement.

Comment: Have you tried my edit ? Use count(). If you want to serialize use many=True and not a list of individuals serializers.

Comment: It's almost the same thing as mine. I just replaced the old condition `request.GET['keyword'] != '' and request.GET['keyword'] != ' '` with your `request.GET['keyword'].strip() != ''` and then it worked :P Thanks !

Although can you explain me why exactly that previous condition was breaking it?

Comment: Well if you just changed that, it's a mystery ! It should do the same, I just wrote it to make it shorter...